# Issues connecting to a virtual machine (RDP)

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I've got one virtual machine in our network which is really annoying me.

The problem is, people are using it to connect to an external client using their VPN (the machine is dedicated for that connection). Once the VPN connection is established, existing RDP connections work fine, but new ones cannot be made; then I get asked to reboot the thing.

There's more strangeness to it. I've added a secondary network card hoping I might be able to do something with it to alleviate the problem, but now I can't RDP to the machine at all.

I can ping it, the machine is inside the local LAN, the Windows Firewall is off, the RDP is configured, the service is running, the port is opened... yet I cannot establish a connection (no response).

What's going on here?

Comment: If your machine where you RDP is not server, you can not work there with multiple users unless you made some dirty hacks(probably you did not, unless other users can RDP to it). Be specific other users cant connect simultaneously? or only one connection (that works from any machine and others just can't connect kicking the user out) ? are your users in network connect under different accounts or using one specific account name?

The second problem with the new network card probably because as i think you messed up with VPN configuration after this.

Comment: @user1448914 It's a small machine only ever used by one person at a time, using a shared local login. With the second card added, I haven't even TOUCHED the VPN settings, nor have I even enabled it. Simply adding a second card caused the machine to be "pingable" but not "RDP'able".

Comment: maybe you have something similar https://superuser.com/questions/190749/initiating-vpn-connection-kills-rdp-connection?rq=1

Comment: @user1448914 Not the same. First, the VPN isn't a typical Windows VPN. If that were the case, we wouldn't be having any issues, as that tends to be pretty standard. ;) Secondly, EXISTING RDP connections don't get broken if the VPN is started. However, the VPN prevents new connections (so if you DC, you can't get back in). Lastly, because this is a different VPN, there's no way to check if something akin to a "default gateway" setting is selected. :(